# Select Distinct Values where ratio of Y to N in a single field is greater than 75%

Tags: mysql

I want to SELECT the DISTINCT Building Names where the ratio of Y to N is equal to or greater than 75% from the following sample data.

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
(`UID` int, `Building Name` varchar(10), `Pets` varchar(1));

INSERT INTO Table1
(`UID`, `Building Name`, `Pets`) VALUES
(1, 'Building A', 'Y'),
(2, 'Building A', 'Y'),
(3, 'Building A', 'Y'),
(4, 'Building A', 'N'),
(5, 'Building B', 'Y'),
(6, 'Building B', 'Y'),
(7, 'Building B', 'N'),
(8, 'Building B', 'N'),
(9, 'Building C', 'N'),
(10, 'Building C', 'N'),
(11, 'Building C', 'Y'),
(12, 'Building C', 'Y'),
(13, 'Building C', 'N');
```

Comment: Next time you should try to create a fiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/ is easier understand the problem that way.

Comment: I tried sqlfiddle.com, they are having an issue right now, I was not able to log in.

The desired result is to show all Building Names with at least 75% Y in the Pet field. In this case it would just be Building A.

Comment: is working fine to me http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/077e1/7

Comment: Now i know why my fiddle counter was changing. Three ppl was working at the same time. Good work ppl .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL, if you say `SUM(Pets = 'Y')` you get a count of the rows where the `Pets` column has the value `Y`.  That's because a boolean expression has a value of either 0 (false) or 1 (true).

So your query is a straightforward aggregate. (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/077e1/31/0)

```
 SELECT `Building name`, COUNT(*) cnt, SUM(Pets = 'Y') Pets ,
       100.0 * SUM(Pets = 'Y') / COUNT(*) percent
  from table1
  group by `Building name`
 having 100.0 * SUM(Pets = 'Y') / COUNT(*) >= 75.0
```

If you want cross-table-server portability, you can't rely on the `SUM(boolean)` trick.  You need  (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/077e1/37/0) this query instead.

```
SELECT `Building name`, COUNT(*) cnt, SUM(CASE WHEN Pets = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Pets ,
       100.0 * SUM(CASE WHEN Pets = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(*) percent
  from table1
  group by `Building name`
 having 100.0 * SUM(CASE WHEN Pets = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(*) >= 75.0
```

These two perform about the same; the second is a little slower but not much because they have to look at the same number of rows (that is, all of them).

Answer (score 1):

if I understend your question correctly your query could look like this:

```
SELECT t1.`Building Name`, ((t1.Y*100)/(t1.Y+t1.N)) AS Ratio
FROM (SELECT `Building Name`, SUM(CASE WHEN Pets = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Y,
              SUM(CASE WHEN Pets = 'N' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS N
     FROM Table1
     GROUP BY `Building Name`) AS t1
HAVING Ratio > 74
```

Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/077e1/16) for that to see how it's work...

GL!

**Edit**
(based on **Juan Carlos Oropeza** suggestion from comment below)

```
SELECT t1.`Building Name`, ((t1.Y*100)/total) AS Ratio
FROM (SELECT `Building Name`, SUM(CASE WHEN Pets = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Y,
             COUNT(*) AS total
      FROM Table1
      GROUP BY `Building Name`) AS t1
HAVING Ratio >= 75
```

Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/077e1/34) for that.

Comment: I like the way you did. I have a suggestion. You should use >= 75 and no need to calculate t1.'N' just calculate total instead.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza yes you are right thanks for suggestion. I'm just try to give suggestion how it's can be done, there is probably more fine tuning to do. I don't have much time now to think about details this is first thing that cross my mind when I read the question... Here Ollie Jones did it without sub-query which is probably even better :)

Comment: Yes, Ollie beat both of us, I dont even know MySql, So just try a normal sql solution. Do you know if that SUM (cond) exist in postgres or MsSQL?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I know that you can use this syntax SUM(CASE...) in MsSQL but don't know for postgres... probably you can google it and see is it exist there.. GL

Comment: In the other table servers you have to say `SUM(CASE WHEN Pets = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`  A little more verbose.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/077e1/32) too

```
SELECT 
      surveyYes.`Building Name`, 
      surveyYes.total, 
      surveyTotal.total, 
      surveyYes.total / surveyTotal.total as ratio
FROM 
(
  SELECT `Building Name`, `Pets`, count(*) as total
  FROM Table1
  WHERE `Pets` = 'Y'
  GROUP BY `Building Name`, `Pets`
) as surveyYes,
(
  SELECT `Building Name`, count(*) as total
  FROM Table1  
  GROUP BY `Building Name`
) as surveyTotal
WHERE
 surveyYes.`Building Name` =  surveyTotal.`Building Name`
AND (surveyYes.total / surveyTotal.total) >= 0.75
```